# How do I install QtSDK (Qt 4.7) on OSX so PyQt can find it?

Tags: qt, pyqt, osx-snow-leopard

I'm trying to install Riverbank's PyQt for the first time, and from reading some other questions here, it looks like I need to update my Qt from 4.6 to 4.7.  I've downloaded QtSDK, PyQt, and sip all within the last 2 days, so they all should be the latest.

I've installed Qt 4.6 before, and it put everything where I would expect.  For example, I have a directory /usr/local/Qt4.6 that has a couple files in it, and other files, like frameworks, seem to be where I'd expect them.

Now, with Qt4.7, it looks like there's this huge package (QtSDK) that include mobile, and when the installation is done(installed into /Developer/QtSDK without issues using the online installer), I look in what I thought were the expected areas:

/usr/include           - only 4.6, no 4.7

/Library/Frameworks    - time stamps over a year old, indicating it's my 4.6 install

/Developer/Tools/Qt    - time stamps over a year old

/usr/local             - only 4.6, no 4.7

/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins - time stamps over a year old

and I don't see Qt4.7 anywhere - I don't think I saw anything install outside of the /Developer/QtSDK area.  I don't remember having to do anything special to more 4.6 into place.  Is there some kind of make install type stuff I need to do for 4.7 after the online install finishes?

Or do I need to add stuff to a bunch of environment PATHs or configure files to point to the new Qt4.7?

When I try to run the configure.py for PyQt, it thinks my Qt version is 4.6(and chokes on QDBusPendingCall), so I'm pretty sure it's not seeing the newer install.

My Mac is Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Went to Nokia's downloads archive website and downloaded the Qt 4.7 package by itself, outside of the QtSDK, and that unpacked where I expected it to.  I don't know why, but they have 4.6 and 4.8 on the main downloads page, but you have to go to the archives for 4.7.  Looks like pyQt built, so I think it worked.

(Can't self-answer yet)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set

```
export QTDIR=/path/to/SDK/root
export PATH=${QTDIR}/bin:$PATH
```

Once you're building things, the really important part is that the right 'qmake' needs to be in your path. (i.e. not an older one). After that, qmake will tell everything that wants to build Qt stuff where it (and its  libraries/frameworks/includes live)